# Elastic Search: How many shards are searched to get the query results

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elastic search, few of my queries are slow.
I want to find out how many shards are searched to get the results depending on query params.
Is there a way to findout?

Answer (score 0):

In the response you get from the `_search` endpoint, you'll see this:

```
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "successful" : 3,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
```

which means that 3 shards were involved in building the search response.